# CRNA project stuck at "Starting packager..."

Tags: react-native, npm, expo, create-react-native-app

I can't start any CRNA project because it gets stuck at "Starting packager", I tried many projects but the problem still remains.
It always gets stuck at "Starting packager..."

I'm using **react-native@0.46.4** and **expo@19.0.1** on **ubuntu 16.04**

PS: I even tried a blank project and starter projects so I think the problem is with CRNA itself.

**Note** 
npm shows me an unmet dependency error with expo and react:

```
npm ERR! peer dep missing: react@>=15.3.1, required by lottie-react-native@1.1.1

npm ERR! peer dep missing: react@>=15.4.0, required by react-native-branch@2.0.0-beta.3
```

I tried these solutions but the problem remains: https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/issues/203

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was fixed by running:

```
sudo sysctl -w fs.inotify.max_user_watches=10000
```

Run this command before running `npm start` or `yarnpkg start`

*REF:* https://forums.expo.io/t/packager-not-loading-on-linux/2034